# Salesforce container access

Tags: containers, salesforce

I created an Aura component that is using a custom application as a static resource, I uploaded the application's HTML file and all it's necessary files next to each other without nesting them in folders, and then I created a tab who use that aura component. these steps are presented in this [article](https://changelog.jointjs.com/rappid/tutorials/lightning.html) .

the application is a rappid_trial app that I downloaded from JointJS official site as free trial package, I did the same behavior with another app in the package and it went well, but this app - database - is giving me an error when I try to access the tab page on my salesforce org

the error is:
Access to {mydomain}.container.force.com was denied You don't have the user rights to view this page.

my aura component cmp file:

<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

```
    <lightning:container src="{!$Resource.database + '/database.html'}" />
```

</aura:component>

anyone has faced this problem before?

I tried to check my user profile permissions but found nothing - my profile is System Administrator -